# MVC problem creating table that iterates on view based on current week

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

As of right now, I have a table on my view that looks like so:

[image]

The purpose of this table is to show a count of how many occurrences happened at each location (on the left) during the current week.

I have 3 tables in my database that I am using to create this table.

**Table One**

```
public partial class code_WeighLocation
{
    public code_WeighLocation()
    {
        tbl_WeighAssc = new HashSet<tbl_WeighAssc>();
    }

    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Weigh_Location { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tbl_WeighAssc> tbl_WeighAssc { get; set; }
}
```

**Table Two - Association Table**

```
public partial class tbl_WeighAssc
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int WeighLocationId { get; set; }

    public int TEUId { get; set; }

    public int OccurenceCount { get; set; }

    public virtual code_WeighLocation code_WeighLocation { get; set; }

    public virtual tbl_TEUForm tbl_TEUForm { get; set; }
}
```

**Table Three**

```
public partial class tbl_TEUForm
{
    public tbl_TEUForm()
    {
        tbl_TEUArrestAssc = new HashSet<tbl_TEUArrestAssc>();
        tbl_WeighAssc = new HashSet<tbl_WeighAssc>();
        tblTEUInspectionAsscs = new HashSet<tblTEUInspectionAssc>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PersonnelIBM { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "date")]
    public DateTime EventDate { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tbl_TEUArrestAssc> tbl_TEUArrestAssc { get; set; }

    public virtual tblPersonnel tblPersonnel { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tbl_WeighAssc> tbl_WeighAssc { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<tblTEUInspectionAssc> tblTEUInspectionAsscs { get; set; }
}
```

Now, my view is taking in a viewmodel:

**ViewModel**

```
public class PersonnelDetailsVm
{
    private static ConnectionStringName db = new ConnectionStringName();
    public PersonnelDetailsVm()
    {
        CurrentWeekDates = new List<DateTime>();
    }
    public string IBM { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "TEU OT Rate")]
    public string Teu_OT_Rate { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "MCSAP OT Rate")]
    public string Mcsap_OT_Rate { get; set; }

    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Division { get; set; }

    public bool Active { get; set; }

    public List<DateTime> CurrentWeekDates { get; set; }

    public List<tbl_WeighAssc> WeighAssociations { get; set; }
    public List<code_WeighLocation> WeighLocations => db.code_WeighLocation.ToList();
}
```

In my view to create the table that I am showing above, my code looks like this:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover mt-3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            @foreach (var date in Model.CurrentWeekDates)
            {
                <th>@date.ToString("ddd") <br /> @date.ToShortDateString()</th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var weighLocation in Model.WeighLocations)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@weighLocation.Weigh_Location</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Now, in my database, in the association table I only have 2 records, and both records were entered on **Friday, 9/7/2018**.  One record is for WIMS/SR-1 with an occurence count of 2.  The other is for FIXED/Blackbird with an occurence count for 2.  So, my goal is to show those counts under **Fri 9/7/2018** in their respective rows/cells and every other cell be filled with a `0` because there aren't any other records in the association table for those locations during this current week.

Here is my controller code to show how I'm populating the days of the week and getting the correct records based off of those dates.

```
var startOfWeek = DateTime.Today.AddDays((int) CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek -
                                         (int) DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek);
person.CurrentWeekDates = Enumerable.Range(0, 7).Select(i => startOfWeek.AddDays(i)).ToList();
var teuFormIds = db.tbl_TEUForm
    .Where(x => person.CurrentWeekDates.Contains(x.EventDate) && x.PersonnelIBM == person.IBM).Select(t => t.Id).ToList();

person.WeighAssociations = db.tbl_WeighAssc.Where(x => teuFormIds.Contains(x.TEUId)).ToList();
```

**Any help is appreciated**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I get this right, but I guess what you need is this, 
for each time you are looping your locations, you should loop your dates again, and then do count or sum occurencecount (depending on your system design I didn't get it) and display it.
You don't need to worry about the cell order because you are looping the same days always so they will align first col is always the first day and so on.
also please double check the conditions I used, I am not sure if it is correct, but anyway this is the approach.

```
<!-- Loop through locations -->
     @foreach (var weighLocation in Model.WeighLocations)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@weighLocation.Weigh_Location</td>
<!-- loop through current days week days for each location--> 
                     @foreach(var currentDay in Model.CurrentWeekDates)
                      {
<!-- Here you count the rows or maybe sum the OccurenceCount  I am not sure how you design it, I used count but you can use sum OccurenceCount  -->
                      <td>
<!-- Compare the location id and the teuForm date -->
                       @Model.WeighAssociations.Where(e => e.WeighLocationId == weighLocation.Id && e.tbl_TEUForm.EventDate == currentDay).Count()
                       </td>
                      }
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: Lol this is too funny, I literally just posted the same answer because I figured it out as well.  But I will mark yours as accepted.

Comment: Thanks Bennet, glad you could figure it out.

Comment: Real quick, any ideas on how to get a total at the end of each row?  I'm working on it now as well

Comment: Total for each location is this   @Model.WeighAssociations.Where(e => e.WeighLocationId == weighLocation.Id).Sum(e => e.OccurenceCount) might throw an error if it is empty so better check if empty 0 if not run sum.

Comment: You are the best. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have figured this out.

In my view I edited the `table tbody` code to this:

```
<tbody>
    @foreach (var weighLocation in Model.WeighLocations)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@weighLocation.Weigh_Location</td>
            @foreach (var date in Model.CurrentWeekDates)
            {
                if (Model.WeighAssociations.Any(x => x.tbl_TEUForm.EventDate == date && x.WeighLocationId == weighLocation.ID))
                {
                    <td>@Model.WeighAssociations.Single(x => x.tbl_TEUForm.EventDate == date && x.WeighLocationId == weighLocation.ID).OccurenceCount</td>
                }
                else
                {
                    <td>0</td>
                }

            }
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```